# Can shouldComponentUpdate returning false clobber a previous update where shouldComponentUpdate returns true?

Tags: reactjs

Here's my `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let equal = _.isEqual(this.state, nextState);
    console.log(this.state, nextState, equal);
    return !equal;
  }
```

As per https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate, this should be the right way to avoid unnecessary updates.

But my problem is, when something does change, it's not showing up in the browser. 
`shouldComponentUpdate` is being called multiple times and returns true at one point and then false after that. When it returns true, render is being called as it should be, but the result is not appearing in the DOM.

My hypothesis is that even though render has been called and would render what I want, react receives another state change before the DOM updates, it sees that shouldComponentUpdate returns false, and it decides not to change the DOM.

But that can't be right, can it? Is that scenario possible? If so, any suggestions for work arounds (other than fixing my muddled code so it doesn't send a bunch of rapid-fire and sometimes redundant state changes)? If not, any other hypotheses?

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate fires also if props changed, not only state. May it is the reason? Just try to return false every time and look at console logs - what changes comes - is it state? is it props?

Comment: The component is coming from react-router and whatever props it's getting through the router, I'm ignoring. Since I'm ignoring them in shouldComponentUpdate, they shouldn't matter, right? I tried your suggestion and yes, props are changing (I'm saving state to the url, but not paying attention to that in the component.) I'm not sure what this proves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though my hypothesis is correct, as yuchy as that seems. I slowed down the third update (the one where `shouldComponentUpdate` returned false) by putting it in a setTimeout with 100ms, and now the render propagates to the DOM. Without the setTimeout, render was being called appropriately, but it was somehow getting clobbered by the next update where `shouldComponentUpdate` returned false.

Answer (score 1):

(0) For sure, React does not produce additional render() or setState().

(1) Looks like saving state at url starts infinite loop - as changed state produces changed props (that comes from react-router after url changing) that produces new changed state I guess. This can explain true-false-true-false cycle at console log.

(2) You does not see changed props as you deny it at shouldComponentUpdate - only change of state can produce re-render now. (As shouldComponentUpdate will return false for changed props with unchanged state).

Comment: I don't understand your answer. `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true when it should and render() is called appropriately, but the DOM isn't updated. Does your answer help explain what's going on?

Comment: Sounds very misterious. Can you post testcase?

Comment: I don't think so. You can see code here: https://github.com/Sigfried/vocab-pop, but I don't think you'll be able to run it without a backend server. (Relevant code is here: https://github.com/Sigfried/vocab-pop/blob/master/src/components/VocabPop.js#L93)

Comment: Well, can say nothing without testcase, sorry